# How to count number of fields inside nested field? - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I did the following mapping. I would like to count the number of products in each nested field "products" (for each document separately). I would also like to do a histogram aggregation, so that I would know the number of specific bucket sizes.

```
PUT /receipts
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id" : {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "user_id" : {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "date" : {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "sum" : {
        "type": "double"
      },
    "products" : {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "number" : {
          "type" : "double"
        },
        "price_single" : {
          "type" : "double"
        },
        "price_total" : {
          "type" : "double"
        }
      }
    }
}
}
}
```

I've tried this query, but I get the number of all the products instead of number of products for each document separately.

```
GET /receipts/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "terms": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "products"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bucket_size": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "products"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result of the query:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "terms" : {
      "doc_count" : 6552,
      "bucket_size" : {
        "value" : 0
      }
    }
  }
```

#### UPDATE

Now I have this code where I make separate buckets for each id and count the number of products inside them.

```
GET /receipts/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "terms":{
      "terms":{
        "field": "_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "products"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "bucket_size": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "products.number"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result of the query:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "terms" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 5,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 490,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "nested" : {
            "doc_count" : 21,
            "bucket_size" : {
              "value" : 21
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "10",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "nested" : {
            "doc_count" : 5,
            "bucket_size" : {
              "value" : 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "100",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "nested" : {
            "doc_count" : 12,
            "bucket_size" : {
              "value" : 12
            }
          }
        },
...
```

Is is possible to group these values (21, 5, 12, ...) into buckets to make a histogram of them?

Answer (score 1):

`products` is only the path to the array of individual products, not an *aggregatable* field. So you'll need to use it on one of your product's field -- such as the `number`:

```json
GET receipts/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "terms": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "products"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bucket_size": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "products.number"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that is a product has no `number`, it'll not contribute to the total count. It's therefore best practice to always include an ID in each of them and then aggregate on that field.

Alternatively  you could use [a script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html#_script_14) to account for missing values. Luckily `value_count` does *not* deduplicate -- meaning if two products are alike and/or have empty values, they'll still be counted as two:

```json
GET receipts/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "terms": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "products"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bucket_size": {
          "value_count": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['products.number'].toString()"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You could also use a nested composite aggregation which'll give you the histogrammed product count w/ the corresponding receipt id:

```json
GET /receipts/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_aggs": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "products"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "composite_parent": {
          "composite": {
            "sources": [
              {
                "receipt_id": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "_id"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "product_number": {
                  "histogram": {
                    "field": "products.number",
                    "interval": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `interval` is modifiable.

Comment: In both cases I get this result:

`"aggregations" : {
    "terms" : {
      "doc_count" : 6552,
      "bucket_size" : {
        "value" : 6552
      }
    }
  }`
But I wanted to get the number of products for the first
document, second document, thrid, etc.

Comment: Separately or summed up as a total? Also, how many top level docs do you have? `GET receipts/_search?track_total_hits=true`

Comment: `{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 500,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [...]`
I want to get the counts of products for each of the 500 transactions separately to be able to put it on a histogram. I don't know if it is possible because I'm new to this.

Comment: I see. So at the end you'd like a separate histogram for each product containing all its corresponding receipts? Or rather a per-receipt histogram of all products bought within that given receipt? Because all the products under a given receipt share the same date which doesn't bring too much value. Please clarify.

Comment: At the end, I would like to have a histogram showing the frequency of a given number of products. I updated my question and now I have counts of products, but I'm curious if there is a way to group them into buckets to make a histogram.

Comment: I think I finally understood what you need. Check the updated answer.